# Duplicate header in CSV file

Tags: ruby, csv

I try to parse a csv file with ruby csv lib, but the file has two columns with the same header text. Is is possible to access the columns `:column` i.e. `row[:column_1]` and `row[:column_2]` or `row[:column][0]` and `row[:column][1]` or should I use the index to access it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have duplicate headers, then, row[:column] will return the first value.

You will have to iterate using index.

```
require 'csv'

filename = "/path/to/csv"

csv = CSV.table(filename, {:headers => :first_row})
headers = csv.headers

csv.each_with_index do |row, i|
    (0...headers.length).each do |j|
        column_header = headers[j]
        column_value = row[j]
        puts " Row #{i}: Header '#{column_header}' has value '#{column_value}'"
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the index:

```
require 'csv'

data = <<data
a,b,c,b
1,2,3,4
9,8,7,6
data

csv = CSV.new(data, :col_sep => ',', :headers => true)
csv.each do |row|
  puts "b: %s, 1: %s, 3: %s" % [row['b'],row[1], row[3]]
end
```

Get attention, the numbers start at 0.

You may also extend the row-object with additional methods:

```
require 'csv'

class CSV::Row
  def b_1; self[1]; end
  def b_2; self[3]; end
end

data = <<data
a,b,c,b
1,2,3,4
9,8,7,6
data
csv = CSV.new(data, :col_sep => ',', :headers => true)
csv.each do |row|
  puts row.b_1
  puts row.b_2
end
```

This logic will define the methods `b_1` and `b_2` **for all** Row-objects (also for complete different CSV-files). So this may be a solution for a small script, but I would not use it in a bigger project.

You could define the method also ad hoc inside a each-loop:

```
require 'csv'

data = <<data
a,b,c,b
1,2,3,4
9,8,7,6
data
csv = CSV.new(data, :col_sep => ',', :headers => true)
csv.each do |row|
  class << row
    def b_1; self[1]; end
    def b_2; self[3]; end
  end
  puts row.b_1
  puts row.b_2
end
```

If you have multiple loop you can also define a module and extend each row:

```
require 'csv'

module RowExtension
  def b_1; self[1]; end
  def b_2; self[3]; end
end

data = <<data
a,b,c,b
1,2,3,4
9,8,7,6
data
csv = CSV.new(data, :col_sep => ',', :headers => true)
csv.each do |row|
  row.extend RowExtension
  puts row.b_1
  puts row.b_2
end
```

Perhaps there is also a possibility to extend the CSV-class to return a specific row-element. But this is beyond my actual knowledge.

---

Another solution is the usage of the headers-option. The headers-options defines the header fields, so you may define your own headers:

```
require 'csv'

data = <<data
a,b,c,b
1,2,3,4
9,8,7,6
data
csv = CSV.new(data, :col_sep => ',', :headers => %w{a b_1 c b_2})
csv.each do |row|
  puts row['b_1']
  puts row['b_2']
end
```

Now you must ignore the first line (the old header line).

Comment: Found this answer today looking for the best way to solve a similar problem, and I was surprised to see no upvotes. Using a module to extend row is very clever! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your question. But if you want to access your CSV data in a table format, just use CSV::Table class as follows

```
csv = CSV.table(filename)
```

[Here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Table.html) is the more info about methods

If you want to access your data in column basis after parsing the data, just transpose the array as follows

```
csv = CSV.parse('csv_string')
csv_array = csv.transpose
```